# Python Multiprocessing - Explanation for increase in time as the number of tasks increases

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have a simple function which does a task. I pass multiple arguments to it.

```
def call_process(processes):
    pool = Pool()
    results_1=pool.map(change_route_thread,processes)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

If there are 20,40,60 tasks which in the processes array , it takes about 0.1 seconds per task on an average.

But if there are 80 or 100 tasks in the process array, it takes 0.2 seconds per task on an average.

Why does this happen?
I want to bring down the time for 80 or 100 tasks to 0.1 seconds as well.

I tried to do this:-

```
def call_process(processes):
    pool = Pool()
    results_1=pool.map(change_route_thread,processes[0:60])
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    pool = Pool()
    results_1=pool.map(change_route_thread,processes[60:])
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

It gave me similar results. Is this a limitation on OS?

Exact Statistics:-

Tasks      Avg. Time per task

10    0.107878417969

20    0.107998579025

40    0.11048762989

60    0.154217456818

80    0.234604523659

100   0.237693323135

Comment: Is that a factor of 2, or is it just the granularity of your time measurements?

Comment: "It gave me similar results." - Similar to what? The first (0.1s) or the second (0.2s) case?

Comment: @HannoBinder have updated the question with stats. The attempt gave me similar results.

Comment: If you have more things, it's more work keeping track of them.

Comment: @JohnGordon any method to overcome this?

Comment: how are you timing the performance?

Comment: @Pynchia the change_route function times it and returns the time to the call_process function